# How do I set focus on a window opened in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps

In my PWA on Android, I use window.open() with a name, but I can't focus that new daughter window, like from a notification click, for example.  Rather than focusing the new window, it focuses on the main window of the PWA.

- Everything works perfectly on desktop Chrome, but not on Android
- if I have that new window open "in Chrome", I can focus it.

What is going on?

Comment: I've been working on this, but need help.  I think the serviceworker is interfering with the focus, as I get a positive result when I put an onfocus(); event on the target window that has already been opened.  So why would the window take focus in browser mode, and display the window, but in the app, it takes the focus, but does nothing?

Comment: Workaround:  if from the mobile PWA I open a window, then choose "Open in Chrome" from the 3 dots, EVERYTHING works perfectly.  I can toggle back and forth, although I noticed a 10 second limitation in toggling between windows.  So now I'm looking to find out how to open a window by name in Chrome, right from the app...